# SQL - subtract value from same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as follows

```
fab_id  x  y  z  m  
12      14 10 3  5
12      10 10 3  4
```

Here im using group by clause on id .Now i want to  subtract those column values which have similar id. 
e.g group by on id (12). Now to subtract (14-10)X, (10-10)Y, (3-3)z, (5-4)m

I know there is a aggregate function sum for addition but is there any function which i can use to subtract this value.

Or is there any other method to achieve the results.

Note- There may be a change that value may come in -ve. So any function handle this?

one more example - (order by correction_date desc so result will show recent correction first)

```
fab_id  x  y  z  m  correction_date
14      20 12 4  4   2014-05-05 09:03
14      24 12 4  3   2014-05-05 08:05
14      26 12 4  6   2014-05-05 07:12
```

so result to achieve group by on id (14). Now to subtract (26-20)X, (12-12)Y, (4-4)z, (6-4)m

Comment: To provide an accurate answer, we need to know all requirements. Will you always have 2 rows? Or `N` rows?

Comment: How do you define the order of your rows, i.e. which row do you subtract from which?  What would you expect to happen if you have three rows with the same `fab_id`?

Comment: I have date column also. I am using order by correction_date desc so that recent correction made for the fab is coming first then so on.

Comment: It will always have two rows only. But it will be better if i do it dynamically (not depending upon 2 or 3 rows)

Comment: This is getting blurry. Please provide an example with three (or even better more) rows with dates and the expected results.

Comment: Please check the one more example

Comment: Write two subqueries: one gets all the rows with lowest date for each ID, the second gets all the rows with the highest date for each ID. Join them and subtract the values of each column from the two subqueries. You can search SO for how to write the subqueries, use the tag `[greatest-n-per-group]`

Comment: I still count two records. Please provide an example with at least three records, so we see which values are being used. (Which is actually what beny23 asked 20 minutes ago already). And please include negative values in your example, too.

Comment: Yes. I have added one more row in the example. As you can see i am subtraction recent corrected values(time 9:03) from the original value(time 7:12)

Comment: I think i got solution for this, pls refer my ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, that you have given more information on how to deal with more records and that you revealed that there is a time column involved, here is a possible solution. The query selects the first and last record per fab_id and subtracts the values:

```
select 
  fab_info.fab_id,
  earliest_fab.x - latest_fab.x,
  earliest_fab.y - latest_fab.y,
  earliest_fab.z - latest_fab.z,
  earliest_fab.m - latest_fab.m
from 
(
  select 
    fab_id, 
    min(correction_date) as min_correction_date,
    max(correction_date) as max_correction_date
  from fab
  group by fab_id
) as fab_info
inner join fab as earliest_fab on 
  earliest_fab.fab_id = fab_info.fab_id and 
  earliest_fab.min_correction_date = fab_info.min_correction_date
inner join fab as latest_fab on 
  latest_fab.fab_id = fab_info.fab_id and 
  latest_fab.min_correction_date = fab_info.max_correction_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you always want to subtract the least value from the greatest value:

```
select 
  fab_id, 
  max(x) - min(x), 
  max(y) - min(y), 
  max(z) - min(z), 
  max(m) - min(m)
from fab
group by fab_id;
```

Comment: I have added one more example. There is one thing also, there can be -ve or +ve value depeding upon correction made for that is more or less. So i cant use min or max function

Comment: Not what he needs, he's looking for the most-recent vs the earliest row, which _may not_ be greatest/least values for that column.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: That's true. This answered the original request, but it doesn't solve the altered one.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you say there will always be two rows, you can simply do a 'self join' and subtract the values from each other:

```
SELECT t1.fab_id, t1.x - t2.x as diffx, t1.y - t2.y as diffy, <remainder columns here>
from <table> t1
inner join <table> t2 on t1.fab_id = t2.fab_id and t1.correctiondate > t2.correctiondate
```

If you have more than two rows, then you'll need to make subqueries or use window ranking functions to figure out the largest and smallest correctiondate for each fab_id and then you can do the very same as above by joining those two subqueries together instead of

Comment: Assuming there are only ever two rows, yes... I'm a little concerned the OP wanted an answer that **didn't** require that condition, frankly.

Comment: As mentioned - if more than two rows exists, simply make each <table> into a subquery which selects the highest and lowest date and the join will still hold.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with Ordered as 
(
select 
    fab_id,x,y,z,m,date, 
    row_Number() over (partition by fab_id order by date desc) as Latest,
    row_Number() over (partition by fab_id order by date) as Oldest
from fab
)
select 
   O1.fab_id, 
   O1.x-O2.x,
   O1.y-O2.y, 
   O1.z-O2.z, 
   O1.m-O2.m
from Ordered O1 
join Ordered O2 on 
O1.fab_id = O2.fab_id
where O1.latest = 1 and O2.oldest = 1
```

Comment: Oh, close - but he wants to subtract the _earliest_ date, which in the case of more than 2 rows won't have an index of `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's SQL Server 2012 that has the handy `FIRST_VALUE()`/[`LAST_VALUE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) OLAP functions, so in the case of more than 2 rows we have to do something a little different:

```
SELECT fab_id, SUM(CASE WHEN latest = 1 THEN -x ELSE x END) AS x,
               SUM(CASE WHEN latest = 1 THEN -y ELSE y END) AS y,
               SUM(CASE WHEN latest = 1 THEN -z ELSE z END) AS z,
               SUM(CASE WHEN latest = 1 THEN -m ELSE m END) AS m

FROM (SELECT fab_id, x, y, z, m,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fab_id 
                               ORDER BY correction_date ASC) AS earliest,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fab_id 
                               ORDER BY correction_date DESC) AS latest
      FROM myTable) fab
WHERE earliest = 1
      OR latest = 1
GROUP BY fab_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

(and [working fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcaad/1).  Thanks to @AK47 for the initial setup.)

Which yields the expected:

```
FAB_ID   X   Y   Z   M
12       4   0   0   1
14       6   0   0   2
```

Note that `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` is so that only rows with changes are considered (you'd get some null result columns otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

I think if you have consistent set or two rows, then following code should work for you.

```
select fab_id ,max(x) - min(x) as x
        ,max(y) - min(y) as y
            ,max(z) - min(z) as z
            ,max(m) - main(m) as m
            from Mytable
group by fab_id
```

It will work, even if you get more than 2 rows in a group, but subtraction will be from max value of min value. hope it helps you.

EDIT :  SQL Fiddle [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10a4a/3)

Comment: The OP specifically stated that he doesn't know which direction the change is going, so you can't use `MAX()`/`MIN()`.  This would also fail horribly in the case of more than 2 rows, as we have no idea what the individual values would be.

Answer (score -1):

A CTE could help:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        -- Get the row numbers per fab_id ordered by the correction date
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fab_id ORDER BY correction_date ASC) AS rid
        , fab_id, x, y, z, m
    FROM
        YourTable
)
SELECT
    fab_id
    -- If the row number is 1 then, this is our base value
    -- If the row number is not 1 then, we want to subtract it (or add the negative value)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN rid = 1 THEN x ELSE x * -1 END) AS x
    , SUM(CASE WHEN rid = 1 THEN y ELSE y * -1 END) AS y
    , SUM(CASE WHEN rid = 1 THEN z ELSE z * -1 END) AS z
    , SUM(CASE WHEN rid = 1 THEN m ELSE m * -1 END) AS m
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    fab_id
```

Remember, 40-10-20 equals to 40 + (-10) + (-20)

Comment: He's only looking for two rows, though, so this doesn't get correct results; specifically, he's look for most-recent vs earliest.